# How many ordered basis does $V$ have?

Tags: linear-algebra

> If $F$ is a field with $q$ elements, $V$ a $F$-vector space of dimension $n$, then how many ordered basis does $V$ have ?

First, $V$ has $q^n$ elements, am I correct ? Let $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ be a basis then for example $\{v_1+v_2,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ is also a basis, So can I say $n\times n$ identity matrix represents the first basis, then for the second basis we have also the identity matrix but with the first row replaced by $(1,1,0,\dots,0)$ (instead of $(1,0,0,\dots,0)$), hence any invertible matrix would give another basis, but it should be ordered, does it mean that the matrix should not be symmettric (axis ?) and don't we need some information about $q$, for example $q=p^n$ then number of elements depend on $p$ ?

Comment: To get started, how many possibilities do you have for picking $v_1$? (let's assume you pick them in order)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I don't understand your question, possibilities for picking $v_1$ such that $v_1$ appears in every basis element or what do you mean ?

Comment: No, I mean you want to pick a basis. How many possible vectors could be the choice for $v_1$?

Comment: @Arnaud D. I got it. But then we have more basis then elements, isn't that contradicting ?

Comment: Why would that be a contradiction?

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft It is a bit weird

Comment: A basis consists of several vectors. There are more pair of elements from the space than there are elements in the space for example (many more in fact, so removing a few to make the set linearly independent does not change this)